# GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found GCP

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket, google-json-api

Seeing com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found exception with error, could not find the specified bucket.what could be the issue, i still have access to the bucket i specified in code. can someone help on this

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm if the path was correctly specified and/or if the Cloud Storage Object was retrievable?

As the error *"com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found"* is too generic and could mean a different root cause.

If you could let us know the full error message, it would be helpful.